# bone tools without change the shape

Tags: cs5, adobe-flash

I want to use bone tools without change the shape of circles. but when using selection tools,

[image]

square changes in this way:

[image]

how can I disable this effect?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Can you clarify your question? What is the effect you are trying to achieve?  If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: you can see that circles distorted but i dont want this

Comment: I can see that, but what kind of animation is this? Why do you need to use the bone tools? The more details you give, the higher the chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: I only want to move them all without any distortion

Comment: i think it is impossible

Comment: if you only need to move, you don't need the bone tool at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37447/discussion-between-user3496654-and-luciano).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try parenting/grouping the small one to the medium, the medium to the large. Then you can go 'inside' the bigger ones and move the smaller ones relatively. It's a bit clunkier than having inverse kinematics, but it'll do just what you want.

Besides Flash, this should also work in other software like Illustrator or LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: The question is tagged adobe-flash—not sure how that affects your answer, just letting you know.

Comment: cannot link to group object

Comment: @user3496654 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAOXR9rhjuk

Comment: I know how to group object but the grouped object canot be used in bone tools

Comment: @user3496654 and I'm saying use grouping and relative internal positioning INSTEAD of the bone tools.

Comment: ok i know that with grouping I can move them with each other. but my problem was in bone tool. so it think, bone tool distorts shape and better way is grouping and then transforming it.

Comment: I can only move them all or move one of them.

Comment: if I move one, other dont move in grouping.

Comment: @user3496654 You move (small) one in the grouping, then you move the larger one by moving the group.

Comment: OK. thanks its better. I have so many problem in bone tool :(